# Webpack 5+Process is not defined triggered by stream-browserify

Tags: node.js, polyfills, webpack-5, cbor

I have to decode a `CBOR` encoded array using the `cbor` node module.

When i launch my command:

```
const decodedData = base45.decode(greenpassBody);
const output = pako.inflate(decodedData);
const results = cbor.decodeAllSync(output); // this line
```

this error is being triggered:

```
_stream_readable.js:529 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:529)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:303)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:280)
    at NoFilter.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:241)
    at NoFilter.Transform.push (_stream_transform.js:139)
    at NoFilter._transform (index.js:220)
    at NoFilter.Transform._read (_stream_transform.js:177)
    at NoFilter.Transform._write (_stream_transform.js:164)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:409)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:398)
```

Triggered by the `stram-browserify` polyfill, necessary to use all of these packages in my web app.

As I read on web, I tried to install the `process` module in my `package.json`, then in my `webpack` config file i tryied in few ways:

```
fallback: {
  stream: require.resolve('stream-browserify'),
  util: require.resolve('util/'),
  zlib: require.resolve('browserify-zlib'),
  assert: require.resolve('assert/'),
  crypto: require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),
  fs: require.resolve('browserify-fs'),
  path: require.resolve('path-browserify'),
  process: require.resolve('process/browser'),  // <- this
}
```

```
alias: {
    'jquery-ui': path.resolve(__dirname, "./node_modules/jquery-ui"),
    'owl.carousel': path.resolve(__dirname, "./node_modules/owl.carousel"),
    modernizr$: path.resolve(__dirname, "./modernizrrc.js"),
    WOW: 'wowjs',
    process: "process/browser", // 1st try
    process: path.resolve(__dirname, "./node_modules/process/browser.js"), // 2nd try
},
```

```
    plugins: [
      // ...
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
         process: "process/browser"
        "process.env": {
          ASSET_PATH: JSON.stringify(ASSET_PATH),
          NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("development"),
          ENV: JSON.stringify("development"),
        },
      }),
```

With the `DefinePlugin` try, the error changed, it said `browser is not defined`.

Anyone knows how to correctly polyfill this module or if there are other ways to use the `CBOR` module?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 13):

**SOLVED**

the problem was that the `process` plugin must be provided, not defined:

it's

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  process: 'process/browser',
})
```

not

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  process: 'process/browser',
}),
```

Comment: It raised an error `ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:`

Comment: can you please describe the context in which this happens?