# ReferenceError: process is not defined at Object../node_modules/path/path.js (bundle.js:674629:17)

Tags: webpack, webpack-5, react-scripts

I am trying to upgrade my react project to web-pack 5. I am using create-react-app. When I did so I got the following errors:

```
    Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./node_modules/content-disposition/index.js 19:15-39

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/kboul/Documents/Apps/earthnetviewer/esa_react/node_modules/content-disposition'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/jszip/lib/readable-stream-browser.js 9:0-34

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/kboul/Documents/Apps/earthnetviewer/esa_react/node_modules/jszip/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/safe-buffer/index.js 2:13-30

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'buffer' in '/home/kboul/Documents/Apps/earthnetviewer/esa_react/node_modules/safe-buffer'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "buffer": require.resolve("buffer/") }'
    - install 'buffer'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "buffer": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/shpjs/lib/binaryajax-browser.js 7:15-39

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'buffer' in '/home/kboul/Documents/Apps/earthnetviewer/esa_react/node_modules/shpjs/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "buffer": require.resolve("buffer/") }'
    - install 'buffer'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "buffer": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/shpjs/lib/binaryajax-fetch.js 7:15-39

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'buffer' in '/home/kboul/Documents/Apps/earthnetviewer/esa_react/node_modules/shpjs/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "buffer": require.resolve("buffer/") }'
    - install 'buffer'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "buffer": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/shpjs/lib/index.js 21:15-39

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'buffer' in '/home/kboul/Documents/Apps/earthnetviewer/esa_react/node_modules/shpjs/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "buffer": require.resolve("buffer/") }'
    - install 'buffer'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "buffer": false }
```

To resolve these errors I installed each of the above-mentioned packages individually, created a `webpack.config.js` and included there:

```
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    fallback: { path: false, buffer: false, stream: false }
  }
};
```

as I did not care including pollyfils and supporting old browsers.

I also tried this in case I wanted to support them.

```
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    fallback: {
      buffer: require.resolve('buffer/'),
      path: require.resolve('path-browserify'),
      stream: require.resolve('stream-browserify')
    }
  }
};
```

I removed `package-lock.json` and node_modules hit `npm i`, `npm start` and I got this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at Object../node_modules/path/path.js (bundle.js:sourcemap:674629:17)
    at Object.options.factory (bundle.js:sourcemap:1195967:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:sourcemap:1195348:33)
    at fn (bundle.js:sourcemap:1195638:21)
    at Object../node_modules/content-disposition/index.js (bundle.js:sourcemap:543216:17)
    at Object.options.factory (bundle.js:sourcemap:1195967:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:sourcemap:1195348:33)
    at fn (bundle.js:sourcemap:1195638:21)
    at Module../src/utils/files.js (bundle.js:sourcemap:235901:77)
    at Module.options.factory (bundle.js:sourcemap:1195967:31)
```

I have tried all the possible solutions that can be found on the net but with no luck including [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41359504/webpack-bundle-js-uncaught-referenceerror-process-is-not-defined) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65018431/webpack-5-uncaught-referenceerror-process-is-not-defined)

I have also installed process library and declare it in the webpack. Still the same error. Any recommendations are welcome.

I have created a related issue on the [official react-scripts github repo issues](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/12072#issuecomment-1189060636)

Comment: same problem here, any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did eventually after upgrading react-scipts to 5.0.1 version was:

1. Replaced `content-disposition` library with vanillajs code. Was used to extract the filename from a blob response
2. Replaced `base64url` library with `jwt-decode` to decode a jwt token
3. Installed `stream` library version `0.0.2` on the dev dependencies and that allowed me in the end to use both `shpjs` and `jszip` libraries as it seemed that they required node env variables that are included in that package.
4. Upgraded then `jszip` to the latest version (3.10.0) from 3.5.0
5. Because I received too many eslint errors I had to modify .`eslintrc` and replace:

   ```
   {
     ...
   "env": {
         "browser": true,
    from "es6": true,
    to   "es2021": true,
         "jest": true
       },

    "parserOptions": {
         "sourceType": "module",
    from   "ecmaVersion": 2018,
    to     "ecmaVersion": 13,
         "ecmaFeatures": {
           "jsx": true
          }
       },
   ...
   }
   ```

also remove `"parser": "babel-eslint"` as this package is deprecated and no longer maintained

To my own surprise I had to remove these 3 from eslint extends

```
"extends": [
   "plugin:testing-library/recommended",
   "plugin:testing-library/react",
   "plugin:jest-dom/recommended",
  ],
```

and these 2 from  "plugins": ["testing-library", "jest-dom"]

as I was receiving the following error:

> [eslint] Failed to load plugin 'testing-library' declared in '.eslintrc.json': Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null Referenced from: /home/.../.eslintrc.json

Then I thought to remove the testing-library declarations temporarily inside eslintrc to be able to move forward but in the end it seems that tests were running without any issues after completing all the mentioned steps

and then on `package.json` upgraded `eslint` from `7.22.0` to `8.20.0`

and finally upgrade:

```
eslint-plugin-import to 2.26.0
eslint-plugin-react to 7.30.1
eslint-plugin-react-hooks" to 4.6.0
eslint-config-airbnb to 19.0.4
prettier to 2.7.1
```

I know it is very custom project related but hopefully can help other people with similar issues

Answer (score 0):

Webpack 5, you can use this solution

first: npm install dotenv-webpack –save-dev

and then:

```
// webpack.config.js
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
...
plugins: [
new Dotenv()
]
...
};
```

Comment: this is not working...

Answer (score -1):

I tried npm install path-browserify method solved this error

import path from 'path-browserify'

It may be that path.js is not supported when the browser executes I thought

Comment: this is not working...