# Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined at ./node_modules/process-nextick-args/index.js

Tags: reactjs

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "new-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "guardian-wallet": "^0.0.6-rc.30",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-error-overlay": "^6.0.11"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "//": "See https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11773",
    "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"
  }
}
```

My app.js :

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import GuardianWallet from "guardian-wallet";
```

I have tried many the solutions I came across nothing helped:

I have tried upgrade react-scripts to its latest version.
Tried npm install --save-dev react-error-overlay@6.0.9 --force.
Tried adding resolution.
Deleted node_modules and package.lock.json and then used npm cache clean --force and then
did npm install.

Answer (score 1):

`process` is a Node.js global; `process is not defined` in a React application most likely means that you're trying to use an NPM package that was written for Node.js, not a browser environment.

Depending on your specific environment and needs, there are a few approaches you could take to fix it: You could replace the NPM package that you're using with one that's written for browsers, or submit a request or PR to add browser support to the NPM package you're using, or set up polyfills in your bundler (see, e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65018431/25507)).

Comment: Thank you for explaining . I didn’t understand why it was not working . Now I get it