# Can`t use environments from .env file (React)

Tags: reactjs, .env

Why does process.env not see my environments from the .env file? I already added `REACT_APP_API_KYE = 'some-code-example'` in the file, but when I try to use it in the api request, all apps are down. I did restart my app after creating the .env file.

#### .env

```
REACT_APP_API_KEY = 'euk4h43l-ertek8-rgde45-gkr3945';
```

#### .common.api.ts

```
export const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'xxxxxxx',
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
        'API-KEY': process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY
    }
})
```

Comment: What does "when I try to use it in the api request, all apps are down" mean?

Comment: How are you bundling your code? `create-react-app`? `vite`? Something else?

Comment: Have you tried console log the key? Can you see it? And I'm guessing you just did a typo in the question?

Comment: @AKX all is crashed by error: Can't resolve 'process'

Comment: Did you add the [`dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package and call `dotenv.config()` at the beginning of your script?

Comment: @nullptr create-react-app

Comment: @Mr. Polywhirl where is the this FILE? (dotenv.config())

Comment: Did you following the official guide about [Adding Development Environment Variables In .env](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env)?

Comment: @pzaenger Yep! but it is not work for me

Comment: throw screenshot of project and location of `.env`

Comment: try removing the space around the `=` sign in the .env file

Comment: @nullptr  useless (

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the [`dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package to your `package.json`, and called `dotenv.config()` at the beginning of your script?

```js
// npm install dotenv
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv' // import

dotenv.config() // load .env into process.env

export const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'xxxxxxx',
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
        'API-KEY': process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY // access
    }
})
```

Comment: I install dotenv, add dotenv.config(), and restart app - Error

Comment: @mustToKnowAnswer what is the error? Have you tried to log out the value before the `export` call? e.g. `console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY)`

Comment: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'process' in

Comment: @mustToKnowAnswer if you search for the error, you will come across [this Webpack issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65018686/1762224).

Answer (score 0):

you need to install

```
npm install dotenv --save
```

after this add  to your app.

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

Comment: @today which file i must add require('dotenv').config() ?

Comment: in your file that you wanted to user .env
**require('dotenv').config({path:__dirname+'/./../../.env'})**

Comment: @today does not work !